# How to read response from web API in C# using HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, json, dotnet-httpclient, webapi

I am getting the API result set in the following JSON format:

```
{c:"2099", d:"A0", e:"01", f:"01", p:"A00101.0", v:"0"},
{c:"2093", d:"A1", e:"02", f:"02", p:"A00101.2", v:"1"},
{c:"2012", d:"A2", e:"03", f:"03", p:"A00101.3", v:"2"},
{c:"2133", d:"A3", e:"04", f:"04", p:"A00101.4", v:"3"},
{c:"2432", d:"A4", e:"05", f:"05", p:"A00101.5", v:"4"}
```

How can I read it using `HttpResponseMessage`?

Tried following but getting error in the last statement in the if statement `dataobjects=response.result`:

```
  var dataObjects = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    try
    {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("get").ConfigureAwait(false);
                
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    dataObjects.Clear();
    dataObjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Dictionary<string, string>>().Result;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting

Comment: @Gratzy No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Dictionary`2' from content with media type 'text/html'

Comment: you are probably not getting the response you are thinking you are what are you using to execute? Look at the raw http response or just read it into a string instead of dataObjects and look at it.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON (see: https://jsonformatter.org/649cf4 , and choose 'validate')